# How can i change clisp's current directory once started?

Tags: clisp

In ghci, i can use "cd" to change its current directory as below:

```
$cat ~/.ghci
:def hoogle \str -> return $ ":! hoogle --count=15 \"" ++ str ++ "\""
:cd /media/E/work
:load Money


 Then once started, ghci will change its current directory. Can i do the same thing in clisp ? Maybe need to modify ~/.clisprc ... ?
```

Sincerely!

Answer (score 0):

It is VERY easy :

```
>cat ~/.clisprc.lisp 
;;; The following lines added by ql:add-to-init-file:
#-quicklisp
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp" (user-homedir-pathname))))
  (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
   (load quicklisp-init)))

;(pushnew "/media/E/lisp/" asdf:*central-registry* :test #'equal)
(cd "/media/E/www/qachina/db/doc/money")
(load "money")
```

The `cd` function works great !